# Deprecated: Function Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I was trying to add the header as a template from the sidebar "template -> add new" but I messed up there so I delete the whole, redo, delete again redo, again several times and ended up with an error to my entire site and now not able to edit or open site

NOTE: using Elementor (free version)

ERROR message appeared after enabling: debugging from wp-config

> Deprecated: Function Elementor\DB::is_built_with_elementor is deprecated since version 3.2.0! Use Plugin::$instance->documents->get( $post_id )->is_built_with_elementor() instead. in /home//domains//public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5379

methods I already tried:

rolling back the elementor version & also disabling auto-update
disabling safe mode
commenting line no 5379 functions and a few more... work for others but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply follow these steps:
Step 1:

One of your Elementor addons is using deprecated code.

You need to disable your plugin one-by-one until you find the one that breaks your site.

When you find the plugin / Elementor addon, you need to contact the addon developers and ask them to read about the Elementor deprecation process and update the addon code.

Step 2:

From left menu go to Elementor / Tools / Version Control (Rollback Version) and reinstall the previous version. Then disable auto update for elementor.